Why in Git Bash ctrl + break isnt working?
I've been trying to use Ctrl+Break to quit a server process, but it doesn't seem to do anything.
Is there another keyboard shortcut that performs the same function? Could there be a need to enable this shortcut through some settings, or might it be a bug?
If possible, please share a tutorial or video link that could help.

It could be because your keyboard doesn't have a dedicated Break key, or the application doesn't recognize that command. Try using Ctrl+C instead, or if that fails, force the process to close through Task Manager with Ctrl+Shift+Esc.
Always worth checking the specific application's documentation for the correct shutdown procedure, and honestly, this is basic troubleshooting you could quickly google
